# Won't insert data to "users" collection to mongoDB with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm having troubls inserting data to mongoDB with nodeJS.

This is part of my server.js file:

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res, next){

db.collection('users', function(err, usersCollection){

    usersCollection.insert(req.body, {w : 1} , function(err){
        return res.send();
    });

    });
});
```

this is my controller in my index.html file:

```
app.controller('SLController', function ($scope, $http){
    $scope.submitSignup = function(){
        var newUser = {
            username: $scope.username,
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password

        };


    $http.post('/users', newUser).then(function(){
            alert('Success');
        });

    }

    /*$scope.signin = function (){
        $http.put('/users/signin', {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password})
            .then(function(){
                alert("Successfully signed in.");
            }, function(err){
                alert("Bad login credentials.");
            })
        }*/

});
```

and this is the section of the form that i'm trying to insert from my sl.html file:

```
<h3 class="form-titles center-block">Sign Up</h3>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-subtitles" placeholder="Usuario" ng-model="username">

<input type="text" class="form-control form-subtitles" placeholder="E-mail" ng-model="email">

<input type="password" class="form-control form-subtitles" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">

<input ng-click="submitSignup()" type="submit" class="form-control form-subtitles btn btn-info" value="Signup">
```

I've looked at the other questions but they are quiet different.

PS. the command i'm using in mongo's console is db.users.find()

Thank you!

**----------------------------------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------------------------------**

A parcial solution i used to fix it:

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res, next){

 db.collection('users', function(err, usersCollection){

    usersCollection***.save***(req.body, {w : 1} , function(err){
        return res.send();
    });
  });
});
```

**INSTEAD OF `.insert` use `.save`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple as simple , by which you can easily create a record into your database.only two parameters are required email and name.

```
router.all('/create', function (req, res) {
        var database = req.Collection;
        var name = req.body.name;// or you can do directly as 'shekhar'
        var email = req.body.email;// or you can do directly as 'a@gmail.com'
        var record = new database({
            name: name,
            email: email
        });
        if (record.length > 0) {
            record.save(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({status: 0, message: err})
                } else {
                    res.json({status: 1, name: name, email: email, message: " success"});
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.json({status: 0, msg: "Invalid Fields"});
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't really understand your method. I just started learning and I'm following a tutorial. Would you mind helping me with my code? Thanks.

Comment: first thing , make your api working, i think for this there is no need of angular , you can simply send data with ajax.
if you are beginner with nodejs then you can take reference of my git repository https://github.com/shekhartyagi26/TodoApp/blob/master/routes/index.js

Comment: I already tried to add you but i can't is there any '+' or '-' symbols?

Answer (score 0):

A parcial solution i used to fix it:

```
 app.post('/users', function(req, res, next){

  db.collection('users', function(err, usersCollection){

     usersCollection***.save***(req.body, {w : 1} , function(err){
         return res.send();
     });
  });
 });
```

**INSTEAD OF `*.insert*`  use  `*.save*`**